# VB.net: "Input string was not in a correct format." Using Convert.ToDouble

Tags: vb.net

I keep receiving the error mention in the title. I've tried replacing all "+" with "&" as mentioned in other threads, but it doesn't seem to work. I wanted to create a program that allows me to see my weight on other planets using VB.net but I cannot get past this "Input string was not in a correct format" error. Any help please? The error occurs at the first line.

```
                    Convert.ToDouble(ComboBox1.SelectedItem())
    If ComboBox1.SelectedItem = 0 Then
        Label4.Text = "Your weight on " + ComboBox1.SelectedItem() + " is " + (TextBox1.Text * 0.378)
    ElseIf ComboBox1.SelectedItem = 1 Then
        Label4.Text = "Your weight on " + ComboBox1.SelectedItem() + " is " + (TextBox1.Text * 0.905)
    ElseIf ComboBox1.SelectedItem = 2 Then
        Label4.Text = "Your weight on " + ComboBox1.SelectedItem() + " is " + (TextBox1.Text * 1.0)
    ElseIf ComboBox1.SelectedItem = 3 Then
        Label4.Text = "Your weight on " + ComboBox1.SelectedItem() + " is " + (TextBox1.Text * 0.379)
    ElseIf ComboBox1.SelectedItem = 4 Then
        Label4.Text = "Your weight on " + ComboBox1.SelectedItem() + " is " + (TextBox1.Text * 2.529)
    ElseIf ComboBox1.SelectedItem = 5 Then
        Label4.Text = "Your weight on " + ComboBox1.SelectedItem() + " is " + (TextBox1.Text * 1.066)
    ElseIf ComboBox1.SelectedItem = 6 Then
        Label4.Text = "Your weight on " + ComboBox1.SelectedItem() + " is " + (TextBox1.Text * 0.903)
    ElseIf ComboBox1.SelectedItem = 7 Then
        Label4.Text = "Your weight on " + ComboBox1.SelectedItem() + " is " + (TextBox1.Text * 1.096)
    ElseIf ComboBox1.SelectedItem = 8 Then
        Label4.Text = "Your weight on " + ComboBox1.SelectedItem() + " is " + (TextBox1.Text * 0.069)
    End If
```

Comment: Always use [TryParse](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.double.tryparse?view=netframework-4.7.2) instead.  You are assuming SelectedItem is a number.  Enable "Option Strict On" at the top of your file.

Comment: It seems, from your code, that Combobox1.SelectedItem() is probably holding the name of a planet, so converting "Mars" to a double clearly wouldn't work. Perhaps you should be converting TextBox1.Text to double, which looks like it is supposed to be holding a number?

Comment: Do you mean `.SelectedIndex`? The `.Text` property of a TextBox is a string. Don't try to multiply strings by numbers even if it appears to work sometimes. Turning on Option Strict will save you odd runtime errors. A user is not guaranteed to enter what you expect.

Comment: Also, in your "If" statements, I think the Combobox1.SelectedIndex is the property you are after, which will hold an integer. SelectedItem, when cast to a string, will have the planet's name

Comment: Looks like you intended to check the value of[`SelectedIndex`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.windows.forms.combobox.selectedindex), not the `SelectedItem`?

Comment: Thank you all for your help! I have solved the problem :)

Answer (score 0):

Thank you all for your help! I solved the problem, by adding CDbl() just before the user input, used Option Strict On, and used SelectedIndex() instead of SelectedItem().

Here is the code:

```
If ComboBox1.SelectedIndex = 0 Then
        Label4.Text = "Your weight on Mercury" & " is " & (CDbl(TextBox1.Text) * 0.378)
    ElseIf ComboBox1.SelectedIndex = 1 Then
        Label4.Text = "Your weight on Venus" & " is " & (CDbl(TextBox1.Text) * 0.905)
    ElseIf ComboBox1.SelectedIndex = 2 Then
        Label4.Text = "Your weight on Earth" & " is " & (CDbl(TextBox1.Text) * 1.0)
    ElseIf ComboBox1.SelectedIndex = 3 Then
        Label4.Text = "Your weight on Mars" & " is " & (CDbl(TextBox1.Text) * 0.379)
    ElseIf ComboBox1.SelectedIndex = 4 Then
        Label4.Text = "Your weight on Jupiter" & " is " & (CDbl(TextBox1.Text) * 2.529)
    ElseIf ComboBox1.SelectedIndex = 5 Then
        Label4.Text = "Your weight on Saturn" & " is " & (CDbl(TextBox1.Text) * 1.066)
    ElseIf ComboBox1.SelectedIndex = 6 Then
        Label4.Text = "Your weight on Uranus" & " is " & (CDbl(TextBox1.Text) * 0.903)
    ElseIf ComboBox1.SelectedIndex = 7 Then
        Label4.Text = "Your weight on Neptune" & " is " & (CDbl(TextBox1.Text) * 1.096)
    ElseIf ComboBox1.SelectedIndex = 8 Then
        Label4.Text = "Your weight on Pluto" & " is " & (CDbl(TextBox1.Text) * 0.069)
    End If
```

Comment: Using `CDbl` will fail if the user input is not a number. You need to validate the user input to make sure it's a number that can be casted to Double. The standard way of doing so is by using [`TryParse`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.double.tryparse) (`Double.TryParse` in your case) as suggested by LarsTech in the comments above.

Answer (score 0):

Use data-binding instead of `If else`
and `Double.TryParse` instead of `CDbl` for conversions from string to integers
and `&` instead of `+` when combining strings(or String interpolation).

> **Option Strict On** - always (which you already did)

```
Public Class Planet
    Public ReadOnly Property Name As String
    Public ReadOnly Property WeightFactor As Double 

    Public Sub New(name As String, weightFactor As Double)
        Me.Name = name 
        Me.WeightFactor = weightFactor
    End Sub     
End Class

' Create planets and bind it to the ComboBox
' Form constructor
Public Sub New()
    InitializeComponent()

    Dim planets As New List(Of Planet) From
    {
        New Planet("Mercury", 0.378),
        New Planet("Venus", 0.905),
        New Planet("Earth", 1.0),
        New Planet("Mars", 0.379),
    }

    ' Bind planets to combobox
    ComboBox1.DisplayMember = "Name" ' Name of the property used for displaying text
    ComboBox1.ValueMember = "WeightFactor" ' Name of the property used as selected value
    ComboBox1.DataSource = planets
End Sub
```

Then your calculation code will look simpler

```
Dim personWeight AS Double
If Double.TryParse(textbox1.Text, personWeight) Then
    ' SelectedItem is instance of selected planet
    Dim planet = DirectCast(ComboBox1.SelectedItem, Planet)

    Dim weightOnPlanet = personWeight * planet.WeightFactor
    Label4.Text = $"Your weight on {planet.Name} is {weightOnPlanet}"
End If
```